# Phoenix Framework - Ports Not Working As Expected

Tags: port, phoenix-framework

After recently updating, I'm running into some strange behavior with my Phoenix project.

Basically, I have to keep changing the port number every time I relaunch the app. I have even tried terminating processes on said ports by PID, to no avail.

Trying to run `mix phx.server` on a "occupied" port yields the following error:

```
Could not start application project: Project.Application.start(:normal, []) returned an error: shutdown: failed to start child: ProjectWeb.Endpoint
    ** (EXIT) shutdown: failed to start child: {:ranch_listener_sup, ProjectWeb.Endpoint.HTTP}
        ** (EXIT) shutdown: failed to start child: :ranch_acceptors_sup
            ** (EXIT) {:listen_error, ProjectWeb.Endpoint.HTTP, :eaddrinuse}
```

This used to never be an issue on my machine (for ~4mo). Any ideas as to why this might be happening or how I could try and resolve this permanently without editing the port number every time?

(MacOS)

Answer (score 0):

You are possibly exciting the terminal and leaving the old process still running. `mix phx.server` always creates a process called beam. Try doing `pkill beam` to terminate the old one before you restart/start.

Its recommended to start with `iex -S mix phx.server` in dev mode so that you type `recompile` in the app console to avoid restarts. Also check if your live reload is working so that you don't have to restart that.